# Update SeriesCollection.Name property

Tags: vba, loops, charts

With the snippet below I am trying to iteratively add new series to a chart. When execution reaches the third line in the loop (updating the name property) I get an "Object required" error. Reading the docs, I think it might be something to do with the .Name property being read-only for embedded charts but I don't know. Can someone show me where I am going wrong and how I can update the name of a series in a chart inside a for loop?

```
With Application.ActiveSheet
    .Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlLine, 600, 20, 300, 300).Select
    For lngB = 2 To 6
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(lngB).Values = _
            .Range(.Cells(2, lngB).Address & ":" & .Cells(10, lngB).Address)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(lngB).XValues = _
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(10, 1).Address)
        AciveChart.SeriesCollection(lngB).name = .Cells(1, lngB).Value
   Next lngB
End With
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Does it raise an error? If so, what error does it raise? When stopped on error what value does `.Cells(1, lngB).Value` show when moving the cursor over it?

Comment: @FaneDuru, The code raises an "Obect required" error. The value in .Cells(1, lngB).Value is the string "Netherlands", as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next updated code. Each `NewSeries` receives a number in the creation order. So, `SeriesCollection(lngB)`, where `lngB` is 2, does not exist yet, since only such a series have been created. So the series number must start with 1, even if the iteration starts from 2:

```
Sub testMakeChartNameSeries()
  Dim lngB As Long
   With ActiveSheet
         .Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlLine, 600, 20, 300, 300).Select
         For lngB = 2 To 6
             ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = _
                     .Range(.cells(2, lngB).Address & ":" & .cells(10, lngB).Address)
             ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(lngB - 1).XValues = _
                       .Range(.cells(2, 1).Address & ":" & .cells(10, 1).Address)
             ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(lngB - 1).Name = .cells(1, lngB).value
        Next lngB
 End With
End Sub
```